# Al obtener campo tipo date de mysql, trae consigo la hora y zona horaria del servidor

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express

Estoy haciendo un crud en nodeJs con express, cuando hago mi consulta a una de mis tablas, que uno de sus campos son tipo date... me trae no solo la fecha que inserto sino también la hora del servidor y la zona horaria.

así es como me trae los datos, si pueden ver me trae la fecha que tengo agregada y la hora del servidor.

```
RowDataPacket {
idactor: '00021',
nombre: 'Rachel McAdams',
fechanacimiento: 1978-11-17T05:00:00.000Z,
descripcion: 'conocida como Rachel McAdams, es una actriz canadiense. Después de graduarse de un programa de grado en teatro en la Universidad de York en 2001',
foto: '/public/images/actores/Rachel McAdams.jpg',
estado: 'T'
```

Y como se puede ver en phpmyadmin el campo solo tiene la fecha.
Aquí se puede observar como esta guardada la fecha en la bd

[image: in db]

Y la estructura como dije antes es tipo date
[image: estructura de la tabla]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me pareció bastante interesante tu pregunta, así que investigué un poco (no tengo mucha experiencia), aparentemente tu problema no está en SQL sino en JS, te escribe la fecha en el formato standard de JS, te mando una página de W3.Schools que te puede servir:
[w.3schools/JavaScript Date Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)

Comment: Ese parece ser el caso, muchas gracias